# Convert list of tables to a list of matrices

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have a list of table `list_table_Tanzania` which I want to conver into a list of matrices `list_matrix_Tanzania`. I tried to run this `for loop` function but I got only one output.

```
for (i in 1:length(list_table_Tanzania)) {
  list_matrix_Tanzania<-as.matrix(list_table_Tanzania[[i]], rownames.force = NA)
}
```

Does somebody know how could I get the same number of matrices of the number of tables in my list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the value of `list_matrix_Tanzania` in each iteration.

Try with `lapply`

```
list_matrix_Tanzania <- lapply(list_table_Tanzania, as.matrix, rownames.force = NA)
```

Doing it with a for loop is also possible, you first have to initialise your list by `list_matrix_Tanzania <- vector("list", length(list_table_Tanzania)` and then in the for loop assign the result of the ith iteration to `list_matrix_Tanzania[[i]]`

*Edit* To remove some columns from the `lapply` result, you can modify it to something like

```
list_matrix_Tanzania <- lapply(list_table_Tanzania, function(d) {
    result <- as.matrix(d, rownames.force = NA)
    v <- 1:2 # Replace this with the indices of the columns you wish to remove
    result[, -v]
})
```